# Unity Microgame WebGL upload not working (500 Internal Server)

Tags: unity-game-engine, internal-server-error

I am trying to go through the Unity Essentials tutorials. The last step for the Microgame tutorial is the publication of the game. I've been trying to upload the Microgame using WebGL in Unity as instructed for the past three days to no avail. As of now, it says there was an internal server error (code 500). Does anyone know what might be happening?
[image]
I found a relevant post on SO where they stated that it was an issue not relating to Unity. However, before the internal 500 error I'm getting now appeared, my Unity Publishing loading bar would freeze at 2% on a different microgame.

Things I've tried: Restarting the computer, reinstalling unity hub and editor, deleting project and restarting, trying a different Microgame, and waiting it out for three days.

Comment: 500 error would come directly from your server.  Ensure that your server can serve those files by adding the appropriate mime type(s).  The loading bar appearing stuck can be caused by a javascript error, and can be checked from your developer console in the browser.

Comment: Sorry, can you enlighten me as to what you mean by "my server"? I am completely new to Unity so you can see why I'd be pretty confused as to why my Microgame is not publishing even though I am following the tutorial. What server are we talking about? What developer console?

Comment: I was under the impression you were pushing the build to a web server, my mistake.  You can try changing the compression settings in `Player Settings` (pretty sure thats where it is) and see if any work without other intervention.

Comment: I couldn't find the player setting you were speaking of. I'm going to try to edit my question so it includes a screenshot of the problem to further clarify what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Player Settings is found at: `Edit`>`Project Settings`>`Player`.  Expand the last section, `Publishing Settings`, and try changing the `Compression Format`

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thank you so much for your help, I changed it to Brotli and it worked. Sorry for the late reply, I was busy. You should post a formal answer so I can accept it. It seems many others were having this same issue on the Unity forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing the compression format, and/or enabling decompression fallback.
These configurations can be found in the `Player Settings`

`Edit`>`Project Settings`>`Player`

There are 3 compression settings for WebGL

> **gzip**  This is the default option. Gzip files are bigger than Brotli files, but faster to build, and natively supported by all browsers over both HTTP and HTTPS.

> **Brotli**    Brotli compression offers the best compression ratios. Brotli compressed files are smaller than gzip, but take a longer time to compress, which increases your iteration times on release builds. Chrome and Firefox only natively support Brotli compression over HTTPS.

> **Disabled**  Disables compression. Use this option if you want to implement your own compression in post-processing
> scripts
> . You should also use it if you plan to use static compression on the hosting server.

In addition, enabling decompression fallback may be the correct option.

> When you enable decompression fallback, Unity adds a .unityweb extension to the build files. You should consider using Decompression Fallback if you have less experience with server configuration, or if server configuration is unavailable to you.
>
> > Note: Using this option results in a larger loader size and a less efficient loading scheme for the build files.

[Unity Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html)

Answer (score 2):

## 2023 Solution

None of the other answers will fix the problem. The good news is, even if your Unity Editor tells you that failed the operation with the Error **500 Internal Server** %99 of the time it's uploading to the server.

So, you should immediately check the Unity website **https://play.unity.com** under **My Games** Section (scroll down a little bit on the home page). You might find lots of successful uploads already there!

In 2022 I've faced the same issue, I forgot to share the answer, this year I'm facing the same exact issue again. But in fact, it's just an editor's upload tool's fault perhaps. I'm not sure.

Hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...
when publishing to WebGL... the unity editor was giving internal server error.
So, i tried to loging to unity play and check what is going on.. as soon as i log in to unity play. the browser gave me internal server error...

So, i changed the browser (Firefox) to Google Chrome....  and it worked...
What you have to do is... change your default browser.

I hope it works for you ...

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue for a couple releases now. Made a project for WebGL and always builds fine but after the upload I get a 500 error every time.  Guess I've made a PC app now. Contacted support by email, this is where they sent me, so must be the correct thread. I have tried all the compression options.